# An awful graph with R

Tags: r, data-visualization, visualization

I've been doing these awful graphs with R with a very basic code below

```
mydata %>%
  mutate(week = week(date)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = week))+
  geom_freqpoly()
```

In the data there are recorded events, in the standard date format, in all four weeks of a month. But as you can see in the picture, the graph dives to the bottom in between of the weeks making it look awful. So how to make the graph go from one point to the other without this dive?

To reconstruct the data frame

```
structure(list(ID = c(82, 23, 81, 76, 56, 17, 11, 50, 69, 84), 
                              pvm = structure(c(1295395200, 1295222400, 1295395200, 1295654400, 
                                                1294272000, 1294272000, 1293926400, 1294185600, 1294012800, 
                                                1295222400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                            -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Comment: could you provide sample data by using `dput`?

Comment: I added code produced by dput. I don't what is the way to do this :) Hope this helps!

Comment: Use `group_by` from dplyr

Comment: @erinho Perhaps you want to try a different `binwidth` such as `geom_freqpoly(binwidth = 1)`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is something you're looking for but you can use geom_point and geom_line to produce a 'better graph'. I'm not sure what the data is meant to show and why you're using geom_freqpoly

```
Data <- structure(list(ID = c(82, 23, 81, 76, 56, 17, 11, 50, 69, 84), 
               pvm = structure(c(1295395200, 1295222400, 1295395200, 1295654400, 
                                 1294272000, 1294272000, 1293926400, 1294185600, 1294012800, 
                                 1295222400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA,-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ggplot(Data, aes(x=pvm, y=ID), group = 1)+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()
```

[Geom_point and Line graoh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpKNJ.png)

New to this answering questions game but let me know if this isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used geom_freqpoly because I only need the count of events that are named "pvm" in the data frame. So actually that "ID" is unnecessary in the graph. And doesn't that ID give a value, that it shouldn't, if you put it into the y axis?